# LG Stylus 2 k520DY not going to bootloader and fastboot

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, lg

I have a LG Stylus 2 k520DY and I want to root it. the problem here is that I can't reboot it to bootloader and fastboot. the adb commands: `adb reboot bootloader` and `adb reboot fastboot` do not work. when I perform these commands, my phone just normally restarts. 
Do you have any idea how I can fix this? 
Is it even possible to get this phone to bootloader?

Comment: LG most likely disabled fastboot intentionally

Comment: Björn Kerler has some excellent low level tools with bootloader unlock options